# Double subscript directly underneath

Tags: formatting, typography, subscripts

Although there are a lot of questions on subscripts none of them are the same as this one (as far as I can find).

I want to write `\min_` and directly under that I want to write `p \in R^n`, that's obviously the easy part. Then I want to write `\| p \| \leq \Delta_k` directly under `p \in R^n` (like a double subscript). I can get `p \in R^n` to go directly under `\min` but I do not know how to get `\| p \| \leq \Delta_k` directly under `p \in R^n`.

This is what I have just now

```
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\min_{p \in \mathbb{R^n}_{\| p \| \leq \Delta_k}} \\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

This makes `\| p \| \leq \Delta_k` a subscript of `{p \in \mathbb{R^n}` but it does not lie directly under it as I would like. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason for using `align` with a single equation? Note that the trailing ``\\`` will produce an unwanted empty equation (with its number).

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `\substack`. (Also, `\mathbb{n}` does not give what I presume you want)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\min_{\substack{p \in \mathbb{R}^n \\ \| p \| \leq \Delta_k}} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Look, Mom, I didn't use `stackengine`!)

Comment: Such a good boy.....

Comment: @cameron You are welcome.  I noticed that with the several questions you have asked on this site, you have never "accepted" an answer.  The way the site is supposed to work is that, of the many answers you may get to a given question of yours, if one of the answers properly answers your query to your satisfaction, you can accept that answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of that answer.  That indicates to other readers that you found that particular answer the most helpful to your question.